# Why does my Python beautifulsoup programs get an attribute error at the same time and then fix themselves at the same time?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I've been using BeautifulSoup to scrape Amazon for data on products.
the full program has been working fine, up until it gave me this error message

```
price = soup.find(id="priceblock_ourprice").get_text()
```

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'

When it does this, I find that every version and program i have using beautifulsoup also gives the same failure, even those are unchanged since they were last working. When one of them works again, all of them begin working until all programs fail again.
This includes  new programs that I write or others that I try out.
Its had me rather confused rewriting the syntax trying to find the problem, at one point I thought it was the header as changing that initally got it working again, but then it stopped shortly after.

```
def check_price(URL, headers):

page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
price = soup.find(id="priceblock_ourprice").get_text()
converted_price = price[:-3]# -3 removes the .99 pence value from product
float_price = ''
for c in converted_price:
    if c.isdigit():
        float_price = float_price + c
        #loop that removes the £$,. from product so the string can convert to float
return float(float_price)
```

An example URl would be: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Sony-ILCE7M3B-Mirrorless-Compact-System/dp/B07B4L1PQ8/ref=sr_1_fkmr1_1?keywords=sony+camera+ilce-7m3+6000+alpha&qid=1574887164&sr=8-1-fkmr1

Thanks!

Comment: share  the url....

Comment: Can you give a sample URL that this piece of code would fail at?

Comment: here's one of the URL's:https://www.amazon.co.uk/Sony-ILCE7M3B-Mirrorless-Compact-System/dp/B07B4L1PQ8/ref=sr_1_fkmr1_1?keywords=sony+camera+ilce-7m3+6000+alpha&qid=1574887164&sr=8-1-fkmr1

Comment: @Lux are you aware that you need to use proxies ? since amazon will block automated requests ?

Comment: I was not, but now that you have said it, makes sense as to why all programs went down and back up at the same time. Must be a timeout window from Amazon. To do extensive tests then I suppose I'll have to use multiple proxies?

Thank you!

Comment: @Lux check my answer and let me know :)

Comment: @Lux you can always check if you are blocked by checking the request response and see what's going on :D

Answer (score 0):

According to your question:

Be informed that `AMAZON` not allowing automated access to for it's data! So you can double check this by checking the response via `r.status_code` ! which can lead you to have that error MSG:

`To discuss automated access to Amazon data please contact api-services-support@amazon.com`

That's why your script might work sometimes and sometimes not.

Therefore you can use `AMAZON API` or you can pass a list of proxies to the `GET` request via `proxies = list_proxies`.

I've corrected some mistakes in your code and simplified it.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'Host': 'www.amazon.co.uk',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'TE': 'Trailers'
}
r = requests.get('https://www.amazon.co.uk/Sony-ILCE7M3B-Mirrorless-Compact-System/dp/B07B4L1PQ8/ref=sr_1_fkmr1_1?keywords=sony+camera+ilce-7m3+6000+alpha&qid=1574887164&sr=8-1-fkmr1', headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
for item in soup.findAll('span', attrs={'class': 'a-size-medium a-color-price priceBlockBuyingPriceString'}):
    item = str(item.text[1:]).split('.')[0]
    print(item)
```

Output:

`1,753`

Online Testing: [Click Here](https://repl.it/@AmericanY/Lux)